# How to add one more column on the basis of certain condition on column in dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I tried this it create one more column that is level but it fails to acheive the result

```
    df['Level'] = np.where((df['DIV0'] != '00') & (df['DIV1'] != '00') & (df['DIV2'] != '00') & (df['DIV3'] != '00'), 'NP', 'Full')
    df['Level'] = np.where((df['DIV0'] != '00') & (df['DIV1'] != '00') & (df['DIV2'] != '00') & (df['DIV3'] == '00'), 'NP', 'Hu')
    df['Level'] = np.where((df['DIV0'] != '00') & (df['DIV1'] != '00') & (df['DIV2'] == '00') & (df['DIV2'] == '00'), 'NP', 'Lim')
    df['Level'] = np.where((df['DIV0'] != '00') & (df['DIV1'] == '00') & (df['DIV2'] == '00') & (df['DIV2'] == '00'), 'NP', 'SEG')
```

Is there any method to create a python function and apply that function over the dataframe by using apply()

Comment: Why did you remove the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this a little differently without apply.

```
dd = {1:'SEG', 2:'Lim', 3:'Hu', 4:'Full'} #Create a dictionary mapping number of Trues to level label.
df['Level'] = (df.iloc[:, 1:] != '00').sum(axis=1).map(dd)
```

Output:

```
      Final  DIV0  DIV1  DIV2  DIV3 Level
0  78797071    78    79    70    71  Full
1  23000000    23    00    00    00   SEG
2  23450000    23    45    00    00   Lim
3  45678900    45    67    89    00    Hu
```

Explanation.

Using `iloc`, integer location and slicing notation, we are getting back all rows, and columns in location 1 to the end. Then we create a boolean matrix to find out position where value is not equal to '00'.  Now, let's sum on each row the number of Trues and use map to map that value to the correct label using a dictionary.

Comment: according to mine condition its fine and thanks a lot it working

Comment: Hey @Scott Boston what if i want to print key in place of their value

Comment: @ParthTiwari Key?  Can you give and example?

Comment: Well, in this case, the key is just the sum of the Trues in boolean matrix.  So, simply drop that `map(dd)`.

Comment: Hey @Scott Boston if i use this (df.['DIV0','DIV1','DIV2','DIV3'] != '00') in place of (df.iloc[:, 1:] != '00') it throws error SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Oh.. remove the '.', dot  between df and ['DIV0  and also, you may need double brackets.

Comment: Also, I recommend reading all the docs... https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

Answer (score 1):

This works for this specific problem

```
def new_column(col0,col1,col3,col4):
    if col2 == 00:
        return 'SEG'
    elif col3 == 00:
        return 'Lim'
    elif col4 == 00:
        return 'Hu'
    else:
        return 'SEG'

df['Level'] = df[['DIV0','DIV1','DIV2','DIV3']].apply(lambda x: new_column(*x),axis=1)
```